# Determine memory size of map project

Tags: qgis-3, memory, file-size, size

I am using QGIS 3.30.1 on a MacBook Pro running MacOS Mojave 10.14.2.
I have created a small-scale map (all of North America) on which there are 12 line feature layers, one point feature layer, and one Natural Earth shaded relief raster.

I tried to export the map as an SVG file through the Layout manager, but the system crashed. I thought this might be due to the map project being too big, so I tested this idea by creating a map with only three light-weight vector layers. The light-weight map exported just fine, by way of the Layout manager, as an SVG file.

So I am wondering whether I can find out the "size" of a map project - in terms of computer resources.
I have looked through the Project Properties and did not see any information about how "big" my map project is

Do you know a way to find out a map project's size?

Update - I did the Menu > Vector > Geometry Tools > Simplify... routine with every vector layer except the point layer. I used a tolerance setting of 0.001 with each one. Maybe this helped. After a great deal of huffing and puffing, QGIS did export the map as an SVG file, and it is readable in Inkscape.

I'd still like to know how to find out the virtual size of a map project in QGIS.

Comment: In my experience, it tends to be the raster layers that consume most of the resources. I managed to reduce some of my file sizes by a factor of ~10, as well as speed up use, by processing the raster to a more compressible format eg in my case, from a DEM, to a classified slope raster.